# How do I sync music to my iPod?

Tags: ubuntu-one, banshee, ipod

Can anyone help me? I want to load and unload music to the wife's iPod but so far I have had no luck. I can see what she has on the iPod and even listen to it through my computer  but I have yet to work out how to synch' with it using Banshee or Ubuntu One.

If anyone has any ideas for a very raw Ubuntu user I would be most grateful.

Comment: It would help if you edited your question with some detail on exactly what kind of ipod you have

Answer (score 3):

The options should show up as soon as you plug in your iPod. If this screen doesn't show up, try removing and plugging back in the iDevice.

[image]

If you have difficulty reading that, the right-mouse-click menu to the left shows "Import to Library" which will pull all of the music on to your hard drive, and the options on the right show your currently selected options for syncing music / audiobooks / videos / podcasts.

Comment: Cheers zookalicious, I will give it a whirl as soon  as the wife gets home.  Many thanks.

Comment: Which program is this?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try installing PlayOnLinux(Windows Wine Loader to run the windows files on Ubuntu) and then install iTunes using it, and then use iTunes to do your Sync.

Comment: We tried that and got a message indicating that Wine doesn't support USB connections. Has anyone done this successfully?